# How to save QTableWidget with pictures?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a table.
When you want to save, I get the memory address 
PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x0000000003E92CA8
doing so

```
    def save_file(self):
    filename = (QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet("diagram", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    self.s_f(sheet)
    wbk.save(filename)

def s_f(self, sheet):
    for currentColumn in range(self.table.columnCount()):
        for currentRow in range(self.table.rowCount()):

            my_icon = self.table.item(currentRow, currentColumn)
            sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, str(my_icon or ''))
```

How can I save the table with the pictures?

Comment: Please copy-paste the exact error message in your question. At which line does the error occur?

Comment: The code works without errors, but it keeps not what you need.
And it is here that he inserts into the cell <PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x0000000003E92CA8>